# I can no longer access OpenShift Online Starter console

Tags: openshift, openshift-online

Around last 1-2 weeks, I got e-mail notice from OpenShift Online that my starter account would be suspended due to inactivity.

I thought I've been using the cluster recently. But anyhow I tried deploying a new app.
After that, I got this another mail informing that:
"Your access to OpenShift Online Starter was removed for account ****** due to a prolonged period of inactivity.
Whenever you are ready to use OpenShift, you can subscribe at http://manage.openshift.com/ to get access to an OpenShift Online cluster again."

I tried re-subscribing, and saw "Starter: Canada (Central)" again on my "Active Subscriptions" page. 
However, when I tried to click "Open Web Console", I got message: "An authentication error occurred. Sign up for OpenShift Online"

Can anyone suggest? Thanks.

Best regards,

Chakrit W.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have no project, or there are no deployed pods, then the account will be retired. You can re-create your account if it happens. If you are having issues with login still, then you can use the contact form at:

- https://help.openshift.com/forms/community-contact.html

to report any issue. I would suggest just keep re-trying in case it is a transient issue.

You can also find out whether there are any current issues with the clusters at:

- https://status.starter.openshift.com/

Comment: Thanks, I've contacted community support and tried deleting browser cookies as they told me. Now I can access the console again!